# Rails :: How to add attributes to a model before sending it to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

for the love of god, this doesn't work:

```
def index
    @events = Event.all
    @events.map { |e| e[:user_subscribed] = '55555' }

    @events.each do |e|
      puts e.name
      puts e[:user_subscribed] # nil !
    end
end
```

I have tried `e[:user_subscribed]` and `e.user_subscribed` and it just doesn't work.

How can I add attributes to @events (I don't need to save them)?

**update:** I basically take events from the database, and add an attribute based on the current_user before sending them to the view. The next lines of code are:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `user_subscribed` is a virtual attribute on the `Event` model, you should set/get it using the regular setter/getter rather than array setter/getter.

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
  @events.each { |e| e.user_subscribed = '55555' }
  @events.each do |e|
    puts e.name
    puts e.user_subscribed
  end
end
```

Comment: this does not work. `puts e.user_subscribed` will result in a blank line as e.user_subscribe equals nil. just tested it again. =/

Comment: This is your answer. But first you need to define the virtual attribute on your model, like so: `attr_accessor :user_subscribed`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the event after you modify it:

```
@events = Event.all.each do |e|
  e.user_subscribed = '55555'
  e.save!
end
```

**Edit**: Most logic, generally speaking, should be put in the model where possible ([Fat Model, Skinny Controller](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model)). So you should do something like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def something_based_on_the_current_user(user)
    #some logic here
  end
end
```

call it in the view (or controller) like this:

```
@event.something_based_on_current_user(@user)
```

Comment: user_subscribed is based on the current_user. I don't want to store all the users subscribed to the event in the database. How do I get all the events, add an attribute to each one, and then put this in the view?

Comment: Hmm I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you should be using ActiveRecord associations (i.e. an `Event has_many :subscribed_users`)

Comment: but it's something that needs to be calculated on runtime. I can't believe there's no way to just add an attribute to @event before adding it to the controller.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I still don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Could you edit your post to explain what you're trying to achieve conceptually, in addition to the non-working code.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. No matter how I can't add an attribute to the model. self.user_subscribed = 'something' doesn't work.